# How do I invoke a sas script in python?

Tags: python, sas

I can open a sas instance but im not certain how to get it to run a specific sas script.

Im using the following code to start sas:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\SAS\SASFoundation\9.2\sas.exe'])
```

Comment: Did my solution work?  Were you able to invoke SAS as you needed?

Comment: @Maurice Yes thank you very much! I can confirm that the -sysin option is required for this to work. Also, I had to use double backslashes '\\' instead of single ones in all my path variables to get this to work.

Comment: Excellent!  I'm glad you were able to get it work for you.  Best of luck with SAS!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass additional parameters through to SAS via subprocess call, but the important things you also need to remember are:

1. You need to tell SAS where to find the AUTOEXEC file
2. You need to tell SAS where to find the config file

I have a shell script that I use to invoke SAS scripts and the call looks like:

`sas -config $SAS_CONFIG -autoexec $SAS_AUTOEXEC $SAS_CODE/$1`

So your call should look like:
`subprocess.call(['C:\Program Files\SAS\SASFoundation\9.2\sas.exe', '-config', config_path, '-autoexec', autoexec_path, '-sysin', sas_script_path])`

You'll need to set up the variables for the paths above.

Good luck!

Comment: Note that if you are running this in Unix, the above will work, but if you're running it under Windows, you need `-sysin` before the `sas_script_path`.

Comment: Ah good point.  Haven't done it in Windows forever.  I'll amend my answer to include sysin.

Comment: I think unix specifically does not use it though I can't verify that at the moment. SAS is weird.

Comment: I agree.  It's an odd bird.  When I describe SAS to other programmers who've never dealt with it they look at me like I'm lying.